# Retrieve data from Database inside Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to call Firebase DB inside Firebase Function. 
Here is how my DB structure looks:
[image]

I need to get LastName by FirstName. I've tried a lot of ways and nothing works for me.
Here is one of them:

```
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("people");
     ref.equalTo("Alex").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.key);
     });
```

What am I do wrong?

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript and/or interacting with Firebase from it, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling Firebase what field to order/filter on. So **what** property do you want to be equal to Alex?

To tell the database this, you call `orderByChild(...)` before `equalTo(...)`:

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("people");
ref.orderByChild("FirstName").equalTo("Alex").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

This will work in a web client, which will just keep an open connection to the Firebase Database while the page is open. But in Cloud Functions your code will be shut down quickly, so you'll want to typically read using `once("value",...)`:

```
ref.orderByChild("FirstName").equalTo("Alex").once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.key);
    });
});
```

If you run this code in Cloud Functions, you need to tell Cloud Functions when you're done. To do this, you return a so-called promise from your code. A simple way here is to do:

```
return ref.orderByChild("FirstName").equalTo("Alex").once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.key);
    });
    return Promise.resolve();
});
```

So in the callback we return a resolved promise once we're done. And then our outer code returns that to the Cloud Functions environment, so that it knows that your code it done.